# sql server where clause issue when passing multiple values

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue in my where  clause of my query.  My query is as follows

```
select * 
from languages 
where languages.Language Like @languages
```

`languages.Language` is a comma separated string.

For example

`languages.Language` might be `'French, Spanish'`

When `@languages = 'french'` it works correctly. However, on my webpage I want to be able to select multiple languages and then pass that into the stored procedure like so

```
@languages = 'French, Spanish'
```

This will work if `languages.Language = 'French , Spanish'` however this will not work because there might be another language in between French and Spanish and `languages.Language` might be something like `'French, German, Spanish'` which will not return any results when searching for `'French, Spanish'`.

I tried something like this

```
@languages = '%french% or languages.Language Like %Spanish%'
```

but this doesn't return any results.

Comment: So, the data on your table **and** the parameter are comma separated strings?. Why don't you just have one language per row in your table?

Comment: I flattened the languages into one column for performance purposes

Comment: What on earth made you think that storing a comma separated string on a single row would give you better performance?

Comment: Yuck!!! This violates 1NF because you are storing multiple values in a single intersection. And denormalizing like this for performance????? Where did you come up with that?

Comment: Didn't want to have multiple rows in my search results, this was causing my search to take a long time.

Comment: so you are saying it is best to have a row for each language and then just change my query to in instead of like?

Comment: But now you have to worry about if the concatenated values of your parameter match with the order of the concatenated values in your table, not just about matching the same languages. This is an unnecesary problem

Comment: How does multiple rows being returned slow down your search? Maybe the issue is in the search logic. It is VERY rarely a good idea to break traditional storage methodologies as a first attempt at increasing performance. It will almost always cause way more problems than it solves.

Comment: if i put my languages into its own column and a row for each , what is the best way to pass the value to my stored proc?

Comment: @user3566345 you might try [Table-Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) if you're on a more recent version of SQL Server to accomplish that. If you're on an older version, there are [other ways of doing so](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html). Heed the advice of those that tell you not to break 1st normal form.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the way you are storing the language field. You open the possibility of non-normalized data with the comma delimited approach. If that design is just so you can to filter a query then I would do that in a stored procedure instead.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(
    @LanguageList NVARCHAR(2000)
)
AS
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
   Languages
WHERE
   Languages.Lanaguage IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.MY_CreateStringTableFromCommaDelimitedString(@LanguageList))
```

**You could use this with the helper table valued function below.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MY_CreateStringTableFromCommaDelimitedString](@IDList NVARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS @T TABLE (ID NVARCHAR(100))
AS BEGIN

    SELECT @IDList = REPLACE(@IDList, CHAR(9),'')
    SELECT @IDList = REPLACE(@IDList, CHAR(10),'')
    SELECT @IDList = REPLACE(@IDList, CHAR(13),'')

    WHILE(CHARINDEX(',',@IDList)>0)BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @T
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@IDList,1,CHARINDEX(',',@IDList)-1)))
        SET @IDList = SUBSTRING(@IDList,CHARINDEX(',',@IDList)+LEN(','),LEN(@IDList)) 
    END
    INSERT INTO @T SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(@IDList))
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: This is the right idea but this splitter has two major issues. First is the delimiter is hardcoded, the second is the performance of this is less than optimal. See this link for a number of options for splitting strings. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings